# How to run plugin code in Eclipse automatically on startup?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to create an Eclipse plugin that automatically runs in the background, as soon as the user opens the Eclipse IDE.

For example, I am building a Java Eclipse plugin that gets the current active file address, but I would like this plugin to always run in the background without user having to run it manually.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Look at the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point

Comment: Simply Adding your piece of code in activator .start method Would also achieve that.

Comment: @KarthikRocky: no, code in Activator.start() is only invoked when the containing plugin is activated. Due to lazy loading you normally have no control over this. The extension point mentioned by greg-449 serves this purpose. Alternatively, setting the startlevel of a plug-in can be used to force eager activation, but to configure the startlevel is more challenging than providing the said extension.

Comment: Stephan Herrmann- Hmmm okie. I understand completely now.. upvoted  Greg answer too:-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point lets you define a class that is run early during workbench initialization.

The extension point looks something like:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.startup">
   <startup class="package.StartupClass"/>
</extension>
```

the class specified must implement the `org.eclipse.ui.IStartup` interface.

More details [here](http://help.eclipse.org/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_startup.html)

Comment: What if I'm on a pure E4 plugin (not application) which has no access to IStartup?

Comment: Ok. Debugging the platform (with compatibility layer) I've found that APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE is called just before IStartup implementations. Would be a good addition to the answer! Thanks Greg as always.
The only difference is that IStartup is called through a Job, which tracks progress.