# How to measure Eclipse startup time?

Tags: eclipse, performance, shell, time, performance-testing

How to measure [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org)'s boot duration, ie. time Eclipse takes to start?

With "Boot duration" being:

1. from time `eclipse` or `eclipse.exe` command is executed
2. to time *Eclipse UI* is started and available (approximately when user can use mouse, menus, and editors)

In a Bash Shell, I have tested the `time` command, **but**, it does not reply until `~/path/to/eclipse/eclipse` process is closed / killed.

```
~$ time ~/path/to/eclipse/eclipse
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
[...] truncated
16:12:32,920 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@4df07ddd - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
^ here I closed Eclipse UI

real    0m11.724s
user    0m35.608s
sys 0m0.868s
```

**How to achieve this?**

Edit:

- a possible solution would be to [write an Eclipse plugin that is auto
  executed at start](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28925894/912046)
- another way is to parse Eclipse logs (I am working
  on this)

*Background / initial goal*

1. compare Eclipse boot durations between different Eclipse
   configurations (`eclipse.ini`). (See [How can you speed up
   Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/316265/912046))
2. See what impact does have a configuration change on
   Eclipse boot time

Note: currently running *Eclipse* on *Ubuntu*. Any advice for *Windows* or *Linux* platform is welcome.

Comment: Use a stop watch.  Seriously.

Comment: Thank for the tips, but I had something a little more precise in mind ;) and that could be easily repeated (to compute an average for example). Currently working on this based on logs parsing

Comment: Well, the reason I said use a stop watch is that I don't think you will find anything better.  Or at least, not without modifying Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in solution that Vogel described here :
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePerformance/article.html#using-the-build-in-tracing-facilities-of-eclipse

The gist is to set a few preferences in a file `.options` you put in your eclipse installation folder :

```
# turn on debugging for the org.eclipse.core plugin.
org.eclipse.osgi/debug=true
# turn on execution time of the activator for the plug-ins
org.eclipse.osgi/debug/bundleTime=true
# turn on total execution time of the plug-ins
org.eclipse.osgi/debug/bundleStartTime=true
```

Then start Eclipse via the following command line.

```
./eclipse -debug
```

Then he even gives a nice set of small scripts that help decipher the trace.
It measures from the osgi component the startup time/activation time of everyone.